# jQuery/JSONP widget and jQuery version conflict

Tags: jquery, widget, jsonp, xss

I would like to create a widget so that my visitors can display it on their blog/website.

I would like to use jquery and jsonp to develop this widget.

I know how to avoid conflicts between jQuery and other libraries (like prototype).

But what will happen if jquery is already installed on my visitors' websites and if their version is different from my version ?

What I mean is: what if, for example, they run a script using an older jquery version and which is not compatible with my jquery library ? Does it stop working ? Is their any workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Read This:**

> [How do I run different versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528241/how-do-i-run-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

Calling [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) will remove jQuery from `$` and restore whatever was there before.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this for the widget?
http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/widgets.html
This is far more powerful than JSONP, much safer, and it has bi-directional transport.

This is really just one of the showcases for the easyXDM framework (http://easyxdm.net/)