# jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, conflict

In my project I am maintaining different jquery versions . so, I am getting jquery conflict please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why still use the old versions? You should not load 2 instances of jquery on the same page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) but also have a look at [Using different versions of jQuery on the same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061618/using-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) . `noConflict()` might or might not work for you.

Answer (score 8):

A simple Google search for `jQuery conflict` would have directed you to the API site:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
    var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
    var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">var jQuery_1_10_2 = $.noConflict(true);</script>

<script>jQuery_1_10_2(document).ready(function(){


jQuery_1_10_2("#click_id").click(function(){
 jQuery_1_10_2("#your_id").toggle();


 });});

</script>
```