# Two jqueries conflicts with each other

Tags: javascript

I have a registration form working on `jquery-3.3.1.min.js`, so i want to include virtual keyboard on this form, virtual keyboard works on `jquery-1.11.0.min.js`, but both files conflict with each other, when i include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

virtual keyboard doesn't works
and if i include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

registration form doesn't work, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ - you won't get very far if you don't even attempt to read the documentation.

Comment: @RandyCasburn What's the catch? is it going to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645888/jquery-conflict) - or use the search feature on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var jQuery1 = jQuery
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/assets/scripts/jquery.min.js">
```

give jquery-1.11.0 another variable name，now you can use `jQuery1` for virtual keyboard，and `jQuery` or `$` for others