# Placing .noConflict() to fix $ to Jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typeerror

I'm having trouble figuring out where would I place the function **try{jQuery.noConflict();}catch(e){};** to get my jquery back in working order.I am new to working with jquery code as well so i do not know where to begin so step by step would help me understand where to actually place the code.

Firebug points out that there may be conflicting code on the site. The "select state" drop down menu does not work because the javascript is voided.

[SUBJECT SITE](http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/products-page/checkout/)

[image]
Stacked Jquery:

```
e()chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
e()chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
e()chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
e(e=select#billing_state.state_select, t=undefined)chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
(?)()chosen...=2.0.14 (line 9)
e(r=0)chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
a(e=Object[select#billing_state.state_select, select#shipping_state.state_select],   n=function(), r=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 2)

a(e=function(), t=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 2)
e(n=undefined)chosen...=0.9.11 (line 9)
(?)(e=function())chosen...=2.0.14 (line 1)
a(t=[Document /products-page/checkout/, [function()]])jquery.min.js (line 2)
a(e=Document /products-page/checkout/, t=[Document /products-page/checkout/, [function()]])jquery.min.js (line 2)

a(e=undefined)jquery.min.js (line 2)
a()jquery.min.js (line 2)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `noConflict()`.   Your script URLs are broken.

Comment: Your site is redirecting some URL you're using as a script source to your site home page. The browser therefore ends up trying to parse your home page content as JavaScript, and gets understandably upset.

Comment: Also there's a conditional comment in there that'll import an old version of jQuery when the page is viewed from IE7.

Comment: @Pointy can you point me in the right direction to troubleshooting my problem? What could be causing my urls to be broken?

Comment: @SLaks what is wrong with my script urls?

Comment: @notchonachos it's probably just files that are missing. Make sure each of your script URLs actually returns a script. You can do it right from the browser: just view source, right-click the script URLs one by one and try them in a separate browser window.  The result will either be a screenful of JavaScript or your site home page.

Comment: We have no idea.  Look at your developer tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using jQuery you would be (by default) using a dollar sign to declare jQuery statements,  <sup>eg:</sup> `$('#id').val();`.
However jQuery is not the only JavaScript library that does this.

By saying you are trying to get your "*jquery back in working order*" I assume you have been using it successfully until recently. This may have been caused by adding a new JavaScript Library that also uses a dollar sign for its statements.
To prevent this you are correct in using the `noConflict()` method, however it does not require a `try...catch` block.

The `noConflict()` method can added a couple of places:

1) After you have declared/used the jQuery Library:

`<script src="jquery.js"></script>`

```
<script>
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

2) You can place it at the very end of your jQuery Library by adding `jQuery.noConflict();` as the very last line

**Note** that when you use `noConflict()` any jQuery statements afterwards will have to be declared using the `jQuery` prefix instead of the dollar sign.

Additional information can be found on the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) or this [Other StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-is-jquery-noconflict-used)

Regards,

Grant

Comment: The problems with that page extend far, far beyond the use of `.noConflict()`. In any case, the page already does have that code, and it's (apparently) working fine.

Comment: He doesn't need `noConflict()` at all.