# Another - jquery object has no method - error on far server not localhost

Tags: jquery

I have an admin page and it has specific version of jquery. I am using jquery to load another html page that has another specific version of jquery. When the second page loaded into a div the methods on the loaded page gives error 'object has no method'.

I have used no conflict with no luck. When i looked at the inspector i saw that the error is from the parent page jquery version.

Do you have an idea. How can i force the loaded page to use its own jquery?

--- **And it is strange that on localhost i get no error while on far server i get this error** ---

I know there are a lot of search results on this. But no solutions colud help me.

Comment: Have you tried using an iframe?

Comment: Ok i will try this. I will create an iframe inside the div and load the child page to it i think?

Comment: Or just replace the div with an iframe, but yeah, I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

On parent page you can use jquery like this

```
var $jqParent = jQuery.noConflict();

$jqParent('selector').show();
```

on child page you can do like this

```
var $jqChild = jQuery.noConflict();

$jqChild ('selector').show();
```

refer this: [How do I implement JQuery.noConflict() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict)

Comment: I do not have a chance to modify the parent... But I am using noConflict for the child page with no luck.

Comment: well, if you can post your rendered HTML, that would help

Comment: It is a long doc how can i insert it here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern that can solve your issue. Try wrapping your code in the child page like this:

```
(function($){
// All your code.

})(jQuery);
```

With this approach, code on your page is saved in a ***separate scope***. When you load another page having another version of jQuery, it only overwrites the ***window*** object properties (`$`,`jQuery`) with another version. Your current version should still work.
If your page have multiple script sections, try wrapping all the sections using jQuery. Like this:

```
<script>
   (function($){
    // All your code for first script section

    })(jQuery);
</script>

<script>
   (function($){
    // All your code for second script section

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

In case you cannot edit your child page, you could do like this in your loaded page (parent page):

```
<script></script>//script to load another jquery version
<script>
    var currentJQuery = $.noConflict(); //restore $ to previous version and return the current version as currentJQuery variable.
</script>
```

Wrap all other scripts like this:

```
<script>
       (function($){
        // All your code for first script section

        })(currentJQuery);
    </script>

    <script>
       (function($){
        // All your code for second script section

        })(currentJQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: @ratata: how can you use jquery to load another html page if you cannot edit it?

Comment: I am using django and have a custom widget. This widget injects the loader code. I am not editing the first page manually. Do you have an idea why the error is on the server side nd not on localhost?

Comment: @ratata: `Do you have an idea why the error is on the server side nd not on localhost?`  this could be a problem of cross-domain when you use a widget loaded from another domain

Comment: @ratata: try my updated answer in case you cannot edit the child page.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest. No solution worked for me. But at last i have solved the problem. The parent page was adding 2 jquery files jquery1.9.1 and 1.8.3. Child page was adding another jquery version. So there were 3 jquery versions. I have found a way to remove the version 1.8.3 and now everything works smoothly. I guess your solutions are right...