# Javascript / jquery files conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a theme which references 4 javascript/jquery files and I am using a slider image which is referencing 3 javascript/jquery files. However, they are conflicting with each other.

What files are conflicting with each other and how can I fix this issue?

Thanks

```
<!-- Code for theme -->
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Code for sliding banner -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>

<!-- Code for theme -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict

Comment: Why you are adding jquery library again and again?

Comment: Do you really need both versions of jquery?

Comment: I'm not adding jquery again and again. It's what came with two scripts that I've added on the same page, so they added them, not me. I'm just trying to work out what's not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** .min is just minified version of file. 
**2)** don't use both. 
**3)** either use .min or normal jquery library.

```
<!-- Code for sliding banner -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>

<!-- Code for theme -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add these:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
```

---

Because you are loading `jQuery1.10+` above all other scripts, so why do you need to add `jQuery.min.js` and `jQuery.1.9.0`.

As this code comment says:

```
<!-- Code for theme -->
```

For a theme you don't need multiple `jQuery` libs to be loaded in a single page.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why the original author of the script I'm using did that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but have you tried [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) ?