# fake jquery document.ready calls on pages without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to use some data in another JS script which had a JQuery call $(document).ready(function() inside the block, but i did not want to use JQuery nor init the script, because i just wnat to use some of the predefined variables.

So simply using the script from external source ( as it might get changed ) but skipping the ready() call and just do some data manipulation afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with

```
<script>
var fakeJquery = function(fn) {
    this.ready = function () {
        return true;
    }
};
var $ = function(fn) { return new fakeJquery();}
</script>
```

But i wonder if there is a better, easier way to do that?

Comment: If you just want to mock the interface why would it matter if there was a better/easier way to do it? The function is 5 lines of code.

Comment: You could use jQuery.noConflict() [Reference post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict]. This would allow you to use your functions without anyconflicts with jQuery functions.