# Example of using jQuery noConflict on 2 jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a jQuery noConflict example that shows 2 jQuery plugins in the same code snippet and how to use `jQuery.noConflict` so that these plugins should function. Where would it apply in the scenario below?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.plugin_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.plugin_2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {
    // plugin_1 code...
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function() {
    // plugin_2 code...
}
</script>
```

Comment: Without noConfict ,does your code work ?

Comment: No, I'm running a Joomla site which implements jQuery and various plugins. Anytime I introduce a custom jQuery plugin, the new plugin fails to work unless I implement improper workarounds (e.g. re-calling the same jquery file right before the new plugin use)

Comment: Just see if the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict helps!

Comment: The purpose of noConflict is to allow jQuery to run alongside another library that uses `$` as a function or variable name, it's not meant to resolve conflicts between jQuery plugins.

Comment: Oh! Now I understand. Well, my answer below still allows my plugins to finally work because they are now properly escaping conflict with whatever other library that was utilizing `$`.

Answer (score 1):

Most Joomla installations also come bundled with MooTools, which uses `$` and `$$` along with jQuery which uses `$`. This sounds like the issue you are experiencing. However both frameworks also have their own global variables you can use.
For MooTools it is `document.id`, for jQuery it is `jQuery`.
As a general rule closures help out a great deal with compatibility issues with plugins.
You can opt to fix the plugins by using the closures or wrap your `$(document).ready()` with them. I personally do both.

**jQuery** https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

```
(function($){
   //jQuery code here
}(jQuery));
```

**MooTools** http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode

```
(function($){
   //MooTools code here
}(document.id));
```

The same issue can occur with a number of global values/variables, for example the usage of some plugins overriding undefined.

```
var undefined = null;
var isDefined = (typeof myVar === undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

This application of jQuery noConflict worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.plugin_1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.plugin_2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $plugin_1 = jQuery.noConflict();
$plugin_1(document).ready(function() {
    // replace "$" with "$plugin_1" in all instances of its use here.
    // plugin_1 code...
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $plugin_2 = jQuery.noConflict();
$plugin_2(document).ready(function() {
    // replace "$" with "$plugin_2" in all instances of its use here
    // plugin_2 code...
}
</script>
```