# how to remove jQuery conflict in Magento 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento-1.8

friends I have wrote my javascript on register page and edit page but on my edit page **I found two errors.** in magento 1.8. I added noconflict in layout/page.xml but i did not get any solution.

```
TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function
http://localhost/cdd_chile/js/prototype/prototype.js
Line 5653

TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
http://localhost/cdd_chile/js/prototype/prototype.js
Line 5734
```

**I am using these script on both page.....**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);?>cddjs/jquery.Rut.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery's noConflict() like

```
$.noConflict();
```

Ex.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src"jquery-1.11.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $j = jQuery.noConflict(true); 
 </script>
```

`$j` is now new alias to access jquery. It has overwritten you `$` alias. You include `noConflict` right after you include jQuery or other plugin where you want to resolve conflict. If you want more explanation please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict)

**EDIT: Sample Example**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $j = jQuery.noConflict(true); 

        $j(document).ready(function(e){     
            $j("#test").click(function(){
                 alert("hi");
            });
        });
 </script> 

</head>
<body>
<button id="test" type="button">Say Hi</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Akki, can you tell me exactly which place does add $.noConflict(); beacuse i tried but it is not working....

Comment: but it is not working. what to do?

Comment: new error created TypeError: $.validator is undefined
http://localhost/cdd_chile/index.php/customer/account/
Line 389

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var jQuery = $.noConflict();
```

Where `jQuery` will be alias to your jQuery library.

`$.noConflict()` will reslove any conflicts that may arise when you have '$' in any other libraries.

Comment: new error created TypeError: $.validator is undefined
http://localhost/cdd_chile/index.php/customer/account/
Line 389

Comment: Are you loading the dependency in order. I mean first jQuery > jQuery UI > etc.. in your <script> tag