# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined - error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, trumbowyg

I'm getting this error in my console,  and it relates to a js script i'm using (Trumbowyg WYSIWYG: http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/)

Here's a picture of the browser console with the error:

[image]

When I click on `(index):166`, it shows this in the source: 
[image]

`id_content` is the `id` for the WSYIWYG editor, and this is the required function in my `js` file to make it work:

```
$('#id_content').trumbowyg({

});
```

I've looked at other solutions and they say to load the jquery script before every other js script, but I'm already doing that and it doesn't solve anything. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? By the way, I'm using this package to integrate it with django: https://github.com/sandino/django-trumbowyg, not sure if that changes anything. I just load the widget in my forms like this:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=TrumbowygWidget(), required=False)
```

full html part:

```
< div >
< textarea
cols = "40"
id = "id_content"
name = "content"
rows = "10" >
< / textarea >
< script >
$("#id_content").trumbowyg({
    lang: "en",
    semantic: true,
    resetCss: true,
    autogrow: true,
    removeformatPasted: true,
    btnsDef: {
        image: {
            dropdown: ['upload', 'insertImage', 'base64', 'noembed'],
            ico: 'insertImage'
        }
    },
    btns: [
        ['formatting'],
        'btnGrp-semantic',
        ['link'],
        ['image'],
        'btnGrp-justify',
        'btnGrp-lists',
        'video',
        ['horizontalRule'],
        ['removeformat'],
        ['fullscreen'],
        ['viewHTML']
    ],
    plugins: {
        upload: {
            serverPath: '/trumbowyg/upload_image/',
            fileFieldName: 'image',
            statusPropertyName: 'message',
            urlPropertyName: 'file'
        }
    }
});
< / script >

< / div >
```

EDIT: keep in mind everything works fine, but I'm still getting this error. This is not a duplicate question, I've tried those solutions and none of them work.

end of the html file, scripts loading fine:

```
    ...
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="/static/js/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/base.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="/static/js/Trumbowyg-master/dist/trumbowyg.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Show please the full HTML code that has the `$` part. That's a lack of `jQuery` loading issue.

Comment: `"but I'm already doing that and it doesn't solve anything"` - Your browser seems to think otherwise, and it's usually right about these things.

Comment: Does it work if you change `$` to `jQuery` for that instance?

Comment: @nik_m added in edit. David what do you mean? My jQuery is the first js file I load.

Comment: @charlietfl no I still get the same error.

Comment: If this is the full HTML then jQuery **is not** loaded. Maybe you're inheriting a `base.html` template? Right click on the page and click `page source` and then copy-paste that. Also, for the sake of the internet, please use `<div>` instead of `< div >`!

Comment: I am inheriting a `base.html` but that's not the full HTML file, the full page source shows the scripts are loading fine (added in my edit). And that html part with the `< div >` is automatically generated from the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Try to put these lines `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` and `<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>` at the `<head>` of the document.

Comment: Already tried it and still get the error.

Comment: And if you open chrome dev tools and write `console.log($('#id_content'))` you get the same error? If yes, then `jQuery` is not loaded. Maybe there is confliction issue. See [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict) for that.

Comment: Just tried that and I do not get an error, here's the output: https://i.imgur.com/BV5sVCv.png

Answer (score -2):

It means your page does not have jQuery loaded.

Check network tab to see if jQuery had issues loading.

Or

Make sure that your code is being executed after jQuery in included.

Comment: jQuery is working, and the WYSIWYG editor that replies on jQuery works fine.

Comment: If you are getting error on that line then how come your editor is being loaded fine?