# Wordpress media library not working - mediaelementplayer is not a function

Tags: wordpress, media

```
Uncaught TypeError: b(...).not(...).filter(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function
```

I am getting this issue after wordpress latest update 4.9. I am using this library in my plugin to allow users to upload images using the wp media upload. It was working fine, but after the latest update it is returning the error as I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on writing good questions :)
Your question currently needs a bit more information to be answerable.

Comment: See https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updated-wordpress-media-library-blank-mediaelementplayer-is-not-defined/

Answer (score 16):

By adding the following code in `functions.php` file, error should be resolved.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_register_javascript', 100);

function my_register_javascript() {
  wp_register_script('mediaelement', plugins_url('wp-mediaelement.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '4.8.2', true);
  wp_enqueue_script('mediaelement');
}
```

Comment: mediaelement is already registered in WordPress by default. So no need of this line 

wp_register_script('mediaelement', plugins_url('wp-mediaelement.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '4.8.2', true);

Answer (score 5):

1. Does it appear on post/page edit?
2. '`Add Media`' button is not working?

If you answer 'yes' on both questions take a look if `jQuery` is not loaded twice, if so, load one only or implement [`JQuery.noConflict()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict).