# How to make jquery gridnav library compatible and working with jquery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/06/09/grid-navigation-effects/
https://tympanus.net/Development/GridNavigationEffects/example8.html

I wanted to use the jquery gridnav library but it was having some conflict with my jQuery version. So I renamed the deprecated code with latest one. So it removed the conflict and error messages. But only the navigation and animation is not happening.

Given below is the changed code of jQuery gridnav. Code commented is the old code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.gridnav.js"></script>
```

```
$(function() {
  $('#tj_container').gridnav({
    type : {
      mode      : 'disperse',   
      speed     : 500,          
      easing    : '',           
      factor    : '',           
      reverse   : ''            
    }
  });
});

//$('<img/>').load( function() {

  $('<img/>').on('load',function() {

    //$p_nav.bind('click.gridnav', function( e ) {
    $p_nav.on('click', function( e ) {
      //$n_nav.bind('click.gridnav', function( e ) {
      $n_nav.on('click', function( e ) {
        $.on( "error", "Method " +  method + " does not exist on jQuery.gridnav");
          //$.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.gridnav' );
```

Comment: Use jQuery.noConflict  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict

Comment: I am using wordpress with jquery 3.3.1 as main jquery. But the grid nav supports jquery 1.6.1.    How to call below function now                                                                      <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
      $('#tj_container').gridnav({
      type : {
      mode  : 'disperse',  
      speed  : 500,   
      easing  : '',   
      factor  : '',   
      reverse  : ''   
       }
      });
     });
    </script>

Comment: I was able to use jquery noconflict and it fixed my issue                                         
    var jQuery_2_0_3 = $.noConflict(true);

    jQuery_2_0_3(function($) {
        $('#tj_container').gridnav({
            rows: 2,
            navL: '#tj_prev',
            navR: '#tj_next',
   
        });
    });