# $.ajax is not a function - conflict with bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a post request using `jQuery` in my .php file. I have a button that on click runs the JS method and then after validation sends the requests.

Anyway, it doesn't work yet because it throws error `"$.ajax is not a function"`. When I'm on the site I can see in the sources that I have imported two jQuery files (the second one from bootstrap which doesn't contain ajax calls). So I started wondering about `jQuery.noConflict()` function.

I implemented the call as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882374/how-do-i-implement-jquery-noconflict) is described.

```js
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'order.php'
});
```

Still without any result. Same error - only changed to *jq.ajax is not a function*.

I got this line in my `index.php` header section and below that bootstrap. Switching them doesn't change anything.

```php
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

If it is important: I have `index.php` file which contains this header. Then in the body section, I'm switching to subpages based on the `$_GET` PHP function, redirecting to the parent `parentorder.php` file, then if the user is logged I'm including `order.php` file which displays additional content and should handle orders.

So I was thinking maybe there is some error with my includes or so but if I can see in the section 'sources' jQuery file that should mean it is imported properly, right?

Comment: The `$.ajax is not a function` error is normally because you're using the slim branch of jQuery, not the full version. Remove that slim reference and use only a single copy of `jquery-3.4.1.min.js`

Comment: Wow! I had in the bottom of the page second reference to jquery-slim, didn't seen that before! Thank you! I was thinking that bootstrap is including this somehow on his own.