# Pulling HTML from a SharePoint page using AJAX/JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I'm working on a homepage for a SharePoint workspace right now, and it would be really convenient from an end user and maintenance point of view if I could pull html from summary pages elsewhere on the workspace to display them within the homepage using AJAX.

What would be the best way of aproaching this? Is it even feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be relatively easy. You should use jQuery. I would recommend either restraining all your code to a content editor web part, or if you are looking for a little more aesthetic freedom, then modifying in Sharepoint Designer the homepage's code.

Comment: How would I approach it, then? GET the page, strip the relevant information and then append to an element on the homepage?

Comment: I just saw jQuery's load() function. Holy crap - I love jQuery - it does all that in one line: $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');

Comment: Haha. Sorry, was sleeping. Looks like you figured it out. But yeah, it's really great. If you have any more questions, just ask them here in the comments, I have quite a bit of experience with Sharepoint and jQuery working together.

Comment: OK, I'm getting 401 unauthorised responses when I send the request to SharePoint. I guess this is some cross-domain policy thing? Is it likely to work when the code is on the same workspace?

Comment: Well, if the page isn't in sharepoint, you might have some issues. I was assuming your homepage was inside of the sharepoint site?

Comment: I was working offline to build the site but it's on Sharepoint now. Still working out the kinks - Sharepoint loads jQuery 1.3 and I've been working from 1.7 so I'll either have rewrite swathes of code or use the trick on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528241/how-do-i-run-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page . Fortunately, it turns out I'm not the poor sod who's responsible for implementing into SharePoint, but I intend to support him as best as I can :)

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to find a solution.