# Use multiple jQuery versions in one HTML document?

Tags: jquery

I understand that this has to be done with `jQuery.noConflict()`, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/aL5HDkTP

Basically, the function for photos needs to use version 1.3.2, and at the same time, the function for nav needs to use 1.6.2.

As you can see, I have attempted to do this with `jQuery.noConflict()`, but to no avail.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps modify the photos function to be 1.6.2+ compatible. Send a pull request to the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the nivo lib require 1.3.2? The nivo website itself uses 1.7.2 just fine. Is your nivo lib out of date?

Comment: It was out of date. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use multiple version using noConflict , use different namespace when referring to specific methods in the jquery thats all.

I do not how you have invoked the methods ,but here is the flow.

```
1.Load jQuery version A
2.call var jQuery_A = $.noConflict(true);
3.Load jQuery version B
4.call var jQuery_B = $.noConflict(true);
```

Now you reference both version with the two namespaces you created above as shown below.

```
jQuery_A("#buttonA")
    .click(function() {
           .......
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything clash with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528241/how-do-i-run-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) on first glance, but I'm getting an unknown reference to a jcps variable around line 44. That could have messed things up assuming it was not declared in one of your loaded scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue a couple of times, the way I overcome it was by replacing $ of jQuery with jQuery instances all over the jquery code.
e-g:

```
$(function() {

})
```

will become

```
 jQuery(function() {

    })
```