# How to use a jquery plugin which uses latest version of jquery than being used in application?

Tags: jquery

I have a web application which uses jquery version x.x.1. Now we want to use a plugin which uses version x.x.5.

Please see below,

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/resources/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value='/resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js'/>"></script>


// some other scripts 


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/mobile/scripts/mobiscroll.core-2.4.4.js'/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/resources/mobile/scripts/mobiscroll.datetime-2.4.4.js'/>"></script>
```

Here my plugin is not wporking at all. If I remove the first jquery it works.

I tried using jQuery.noConflict(), but no use.

Note:- Since this is old application developed by someone else, we dont want to touch their scripts or upgrade the jquery version altogether  as it may break some code which we may not be even aware of.

The application seems to be using many versions of jquery altogether and its creating a lot of problems and confilcts at so many places.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the jQuery-migrate tool? https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

Answer (score 0):

Including jQuery twice on the page will lead to disasters, which it sounds like you've run into. I'd honestly recommend against going down this road since you're introducing a lot of technical debt into the application. I would sit down and take the time to fix all of the jQuery versions to one unified version to allow for easier future growth.

If you're deadset on this, take a look at [How do I run different versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528241/how-do-i-run-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page) which explains the order you'll need to do it in.