# How to run multiple versions of Zepto.js on one page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zepto

Can somebody please explain me how could I make different builds for Zepto.js (in order to include touch support) in a noob-friendly way, because I cannot find detailed instructions anywhere on the Internet.

Comment: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto#readme ?

Comment: This is the jQuery way of running multiple instances. As Zepto.js is built on jQuery it shouldn't be hard to find an equal solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528241/how-do-i-run-different-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: @Allendar: Well not built *on* jQuery, but built *similarly to* jQuery.

Comment: You got me there, thanks for the note icktoofay :)

Comment: Don't close, it's a useful question.

Answer (score 5):

This should work, just like jQuery does it:

```
<script src="zepto1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var zep10 = window.Zepto;
</script>

<script src="zepto0.8.js"></script>
<script>
    var zep08 = window.Zepto;
</script>
```

Zepto does not need to be "compiled". It just needs to be placed into a variable, like jQuery and MooTools go into `$` by default. You can set the most used version of Zepto into `$` too if you like:

```
<script src="zepto1.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ = window.Zepto;
</script>
```

Off-course you need to trigger your commands from those objects from then on.

For version `1.0` you would just use your normal `$.()` operations. But for version `0.8` you would use `zep08.()` to call actions.

**Note**

From the Zepto homepage (http://zeptojs.com):

> Zepto will only set the $ global to itself if it is not yet defined. There is no Zepto.noConflict method.

So if you already loaded jQuery or MooTools, it will not break the `$` binding, as long as you have those libraries load before Zepto does. Otherwise you will still get overwrites.

**Tests**

Also check this out: http://jsperf.com/qwery-vs-jquery-vs-mootools-selector-engines/11. On Chrome and Safari jQuery wins big from Zepto. So you might have a lighter "initial load" with Zepto, but it seems jQuery wins performance-wise.

I've tested on `Safari 6.0.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.3` with these results:

Jeesh / ID

- Jeesh("#n-contents");
- 40,136 | ±3.78% | 95% slower

jQuery / ID

- jQuery("#n-contents");
- 765,799 | ±4.36% | fastest

Zepto / ID

- Zepto("#n-contents");
- 348,956 | ±4.89% | 55% slower

Jeesh / class

- Jeesh(".firstHeading");
- 40,748 | ±3.96% | 95% slower

jQuery / class

- jQuery(".firstHeading");
- 306,591 | ±4.31% | 60% slower

Zepto / class

- Zepto(".firstHeading");
- 284,822 | ±3.92% | 63% slower